# MSAccess populate multiple fields with a single pulldown

Tags: database, forms, ms-access, ms-access-2010, auto-populate

Challenge: I've created a simple repository in MSACCESS **(#1)** that displays one or more owners of a corporate server.

[image]

The sub-form "asset-owners" is linked to the corp-assets main-form **(#2)**. I've added a pulldown whereby the user can select a name **(#3)** from the address_book **(#4)** table and prepopulate the owners sub-form.

Objective: I would like to auto populate the associated "Occupation", "Favorite Food", and "Favorite Movie" fields when the user selects a name from the pulldown **(#5)**.

[image]

I am not exactly sure how I should configure the occupation food and movie fields to auto-populate with such data AFTER the user has selected the name. I was thinking an inline query for each field, but I suspect it may be simpler than that.

Note: occupation, food, and movie data comes from the address_book **(#4)**.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you don't want to repeat data in another table. If you just want to display the related data, options:

1. create multi-column combobox then expression in textbox references combobox column by index - index begins with 0 `=[comboboxname].Column(1)`
2. include lookup table in form RecordSource and bind textboxes to fields - set them Locked Yes and TabStop No
3. DLookup() expression in textbox.

Comment: As always a truly amazing solution. I used the AfterUpdate Event to then populate the fields using option 2. To your question regarding dupe data. Sadly the user does want to see the associated data and I don't know a cleaner way to present this other than to post it to another table for safe keeping and presentation.

Comment: But the suggested methods do show related data without having to save into another table. So unless need to save this data to preserve history because attributes change over time, don't duplicate data.