# Access VBA After Insert Autofill?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm looking for a little help/input on how to have a field auto-populate after an identification number is entered in a new record.

I have an entry screen ("RetailEntry") where someone will enter a "Pack Number" once they either move to another record I'd like the "Description" field to populate with the corresponding "Description" ("qryDescriptions") for that pack number.

Example:
If I enter pack number 6781234 it would give me the Description "Test"

I'm trying to figure out the best way of doing this and I thought maybe a record loop like below where it runs a query for the pack number and description then loops through the records to fill it in. It kinda works if I only enter one pack number but adding anymore pack numbers or copy and pasting multiple pack numbers it errors with a "No Current Record" which I'm guessing has to do with the order of processes. I am really hoping there is a way to do this where it will autofill vs me having to add a button to make this work.

Any thoughts, advice or help is greatly appreciated!!

Code:

```
Private Sub Form_AfterInsert()
Dim db As Dao.Database
Dim Desc As String
Dim PDesc As String
Dim rs As Dao.Recordset
Dim rq As Dao.Recordset

'Set Description
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("RetailEntry")
Set rq = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("qryDescriptions")

PDesc = rs.Fields("Pack_Number").Value

Desc = "SELECT DISTINCT PackNum, Description " _
        & " FROM PIC704Current " _
        & " WHERE Packnum = '" & PDesc & "'"
strSQL = Desc

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
db.QueryDefs.Delete "qryDescriptions"
Set qdfPassThrough = db.CreateQueryDef("qryDescriptions")
qdfPassThrough.Connect = "ODBC;DSN=SupplyChainMisc;Description=SupplyChainMisc;Trusted_Connection=Yes;DATABASE=SupplyChain_Misc;"
qdfPassThrough.ReturnsRecords = True
qdfPassThrough.ODBCTimeout = 180
qdfPassThrough.SQL = strSQL
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'Loop version
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then
rs.MoveFirst
rq.MoveFirst
Do Until rs.EOF = True
    If rs.Fields("Description").Value <> rq.Fields("Description").Value Then
    Else
        Me!Description.Value = rq.Fields("Description").Value
    End If
rs.MoveNext
rq.MoveNext
Loop
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Question and code is confusing me. :) It sounds like a simple lookup, no loops are necessary. If you want to process multiple numbers in one go, you need to **split** them first and process them separately (then in a loop).

Comment: @Andre sorry, I'm not as articulate as I'd like to be. My Covid booster has caused a lot of pain and my arm killing me. I was thinking there has to be a way to just be able to do a simple lookup maybe from the Table ("RetailEntry") or something. Just not exactly sure how to make that happen. I'll see if I can find some resources on how to do a lookup to another table or query.

Comment: DLookup() is the easiest way. Usually things like these are done in the AfterUpdate event of the input control, not in Form_AfterInsert. But note that I don't fully understand your setup. A screenshot of the form could help if it isn't as simple as I think.

Comment: @Andre Thanks! I'm looking over the Syntax and use of Dlookup() now. I've never used that in Access but I assume it's similar to Vlookup in excel? Kinda looks like I need to setup a combo box from my table then do some VBA code on the form for afterupdate. Does that sound about right? Thanks for your help btw!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MSAccess Populate multiple fields with a single pulldown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68091879/msaccess-populate-multiple-fields-with-a-single-pulldown)

Comment: No VBA code is necessary unless you want to save the lookup data into data record and that is likely not necessary in this case.

Comment: @June7 Thanks I think this does! I'll give it a look through and check it out! Thank you!

Comment: @June7 Need a little more input. What I've done is created a query called "qryDescriptions" This query has Fields "PackNum" and "Description". In the form "RetailEntry" I've created a text box with the following: `=DLookUp("Description","qryDescriptions","PackNum=" & [Pack_Number])`  If I'm understanding the Dlookup right it should be looking up the description when PackNum in qryDescriptions = Pack_Number from the RetailEntry's form. But right now it just gives #error.

Comment: Is PackNum a text field? If so, use apostrophe delimiters `"PackNum='" & [Pack_Number] & "'"`. The other 2 methods are preferred over DLookup which can cause slow performance.

Comment: @June7 Yes PackNum in the qryDescriptions is pulled from a Short Text column. I've used your change but now the field just comes up blank. The error is gone though. Is there any other info I can get you that would help?

Comment: The qryDescriptions has records when viewed in datasheet? Why reference query and not just table in DLookup? [Pack_Number] is name of textbox or combobox? Try the other 2 methods. Could post to a forum that allows attaching files and provide db for analysis.

Comment: I switched to a table instead of the query and it worked. Thanks so much for your help!